# Smplifying my nested if statement in RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement, search

I have trouble in building nested if statements. I have an index page in which I show records based on some condition. My controller code for that is,

```
def index_orderSummary
  if Date.today.month>=4
    @order_summary = OrderSummary.where(:created_at=>("#{Time.now.year}-04-01")..("#{Time.now.year+1}-03-31"))
  else
    @order_summary = OrderSummary.where(:created_at=>("#{Time.now.year-1}-04-01")..("#{Time.now.year}-03-31"))
  end
  @order_summary = @order_summary.paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(10).order("order_no ASC")
end

def index_issues
    @user = User.new
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id]).name
    if Date.today.month>=4
      @issue = Issue.where(:created_at=>("#{Time.now.year}-04-01")..("#{Time.now.year+1}-03-31"))
    else
      @issue = Issue.where(:created_at=>("#{Time.now.year-1}-04-01")..("#{Time.now.year}-03-31"))
    end
    @issue = @issue.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).order("issue_slip_no ASC")
  end
```

I have used a search box for which I have written the following method
in the controller.

```
def search
  if params[:id] == "search-order" then
    @order_summary = OrderSummary.where(:created_at=>("#{Time.now.year}-04-01")..("#{Time.now.year+1}-03-31")).search(params[:search])
    @order_summary = @order_summary.paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(5).order('order_no ASC')
    render :action => :index_orderSummary
  elsif params[:id] == "search-issue" then
    @issue = Issue.where(:created_at=>("#{Time.now.year}-04-01")..("#{Time.now.year+1}-03-31")).search(params[:search])
    @issue = @issue.paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(10).order("issue_slip_no ASC")
    render :action => :index_issues
  end
end
```

now what all I need is, I want to integrate both my search and index
methods.

My index methods already having an if else statement., now i want to
check if params comes from search then I want to display the searched
results in the index. How do I achieve that? Pls intimate, if my
question is not clear..

Kindly please help and
correct me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to search if `params[:id]` is present and display your index if it is not? Which of the index methods do you want to integrate or do you want both indexes to be able to search? I'm guessing the two indexes match two different pages in your scenario.

Comment: @ollaollu, By default I want to display the index page and there I give a search box, after which the search results should be displayed in the same index page. I want to integrate index_orderSummary with its respective search functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way to go about this is to provide a reusable way to return the order summaries and the issues in the default case (without a search), and then applying search filters on top of the base results. To do that, I would define methods to retrieve the default cases, so that they can be reused in the different sections of the if-else statements. Usually, if you have lots of nested if statements, you can clean it up by creating methods. It would look roughly something like this:

```
def index_orderSummary
  if params[:id] = "search-order"
    @order_summary = order_summary.search(params[:search])
      .paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(5).order('order_no ASC')
  else
    @order_summary = order_summary
      .paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(10).order("order_no ASC")
  end
end

def index_issues
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id]).name
  if params[:id] = "search-issue"
    @issue= issue.search(params[:search])
      .paginate(page: params[:page]).per_page(10).order("issue_slip_no ASC")
  else
      @issue = issue.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).order("issue_slip_no ASC")
  end
end

def order_summary
  if Date.today.month>=4
    return OrderSummary.where(:created_at=>("#{Time.now.year}-04-01")..("#{Time.now.year+1}-03-31"))
  else
    return OrderSummary.where(:created_at=>("#{Time.now.year-1}-04-01")..("#{Time.now.year}-03-31"))
  end
end

def issue
  if Date.today.month>=4
    return Issue.where(:created_at=>("#{Time.now.year}-04-01")..("#{Time.now.year+1}-03-31"))
  else
    return Issue.where(:created_at=>("#{Time.now.year-1}-04-01")..("#{Time.now.year}-03-31"))
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I think ur answer will work. But could u explain me more clearly please. I am just a beginner. Do i want to create a views for def order_summary and def issue?? Why return statements? Please explain..

Comment: You don't need views for def order_summary and def issue. These are just typical methods used by def index_orderSummary and def index_issues in order to retrieve a list of order summaries and issues from your database. I put them in methods so that you can do this data retrieval simply by calling the method, rather than writing out the same lines of code more than once. The aim is to write DRY code (Don't repeat yourself). I used return statements because these methods MUST return a collection of order summaries or issues.

Comment: See this line in the code for example: order_summary.search(params[:search]). Here I am calling def order_summary and it will return the order_summaries by performing the where operation in the method. It then returns the results back to the index method and applies .search(params[:search])

Comment: Thank you @hypern. But pagination for search not working.

Comment: Its difficult to tell why without knowing what the search method does.

Comment: Search method searches from the listed index and display the result in the same index page. Now what happens is, It is rendering the pagination with correct count. But when I click on the second page, It actually goes to the second page of the actual index page. not sure what is happening.

Comment: Are you attempting to paginate more than one data collection? If so, you can define the page name for each data collection. Otherwise when you click page two, are the search params persisting? If they are not, it would explain why the data collection returns to the 'actual' page index.

Answer (score 0):

**You can split in two controllers**

It seems you're trying to return two different resources through the same controller, which is never a good idea nor good practice. I would at least split the controller actions and create two separate routes. It's cleaner.

```
class OrderSummariesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # your code for finding order summaries
  end
end

class IssuesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # your code for finding issues
  end
end
```

You could then use the same view template to show the results if that's why you were doing all in the same controller initially. But I would advise separating also the templates, reusing the common parts in partials.

**You need it to be in the same controller**

If for any reason you *absolutely* have to use the same controller action, for instance if your search bar has a dropdown that lets you choose which kind of results to show, then I'd move all that logic in a PORO to deal with the logic, like this:

```
class SearchResultsFactory
  def self.search_for_type type, query, page
    self.send(type.underscore, query, page)
  end

  def self.search_order query, page
    # your code for finding order summaries
  end

  def self.search_issue query, page
    # your code for finding issues
  end
end
```

And then in your controller you'd just have to do:

```
def index
  @results = SearchResultsService.search_for_type(params[:id], params[:search], params[:page])
end
```

It's cleaner and gives you more flexibility to add more types of elements to search, just add a method named after the type you're searching and it will be supported out of the box.